# How to setup a MySql server to accept remote connections?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, networking

I am installing a MySql server in Ubuntu desktop. I could connect MySql Query Browser to it when specifying the `Server Hostname` as `localhost`, but when I replace it by the machine's IP it stops working (even if the MySql Query Browser runs in the same machine).

All I have done so far is removing the iptables, but it seems it have nothing to do with it.

Here is the error message

> Could not connect to host '192.168.0.2'.
>
> MySQL Error Nr. 2003
>
> Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.2' (111)
>
> Click the 'Ping' button to see if there is a networking problem.

The ping is ok, though

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You'll have to bind your mysqld to a IP different from 127.0.0.1.

Open your my.cnf (/etc/mysql/my.cnf usually) and change the line that says

```
bind = 127.0.0.1
```

to whatever IP your machine uses to connect to the outside world. `0.0.0.0` binds to all IP addresses. Don't forget to restart your mysqld after that change.

Comment: got a different error now:
Could not connect to host '192.168.0.2'.
MySQL Error Nr. 1130
Host 'whatever-vubuntu.local' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Comment: user@localhost and user@<hostname> is different.  You have to add the user to be able to connect from remote hosts.

Comment: This is not the problem. I've done this and I still get the error.

Comment: Should that be `bind-address`?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to halfdan answer I had to execute the following mysql command:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP
ON databasename.*
TO 'username'@'clientipaddress'
IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

As I learned on

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?86,23619,41248#msg-41248

Answer (score 2):

Several more potential problems explained here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html

If you want to grant all privileges to all databases, try

`grant all on *.* to 'joe'@'%';`

However, before you do that, make sure you have a user in the "mysql" database that has "Host" set to your IP address--in my case, my IP here at home.  So user "joe" may have more than one record, one for each IP he might be calling from.  To see what you have in there already:

```
use mysql;
select Host, User, Password from user where user='joe';`
```

In my case, turned out my user now had the correct IP but the password was also missing.  I cut-pasted the password (it's hashed or something) and this solved my particular remote connection problem:

`update user set Password='5493845039485' where user='joe';`

One more thing, in my.cnf you may want to set "port=3306" or whatever port you plan to use.