# Amazon AWS VPC how to open a port?

Tags: firewall, routing, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to setup a MySql server to accept remote connections?](https://serverfault.com/questions/91482/how-to-setup-a-mysql-server-to-accept-remote-connections)

I have a VPN with public and private subnets; I am considering only public subnet for now.

The node 10.0.0.23, I can ssh into it. Let's say I want to connect to MySQL on the node using its private address:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-23:/$ mysql -u root -h 10.0.0.23
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.0.23' (111)

ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-23:/$ mysql -u root -h localhost
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
--- 8< --- snip --- 8< --- 
mysql>
```

The port 3306 is not reachable if I use the private IP?

My security group allows port 3306 inbound from 0.0.0.0/0 AND from 10.0.0.0/24. Outbound, allowed all.
The generic setup done by Amazon through their wizard does not work... I add ACL that allows everything for everybody, still does not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you mean AWS VPC perhaps?

Comment: Michael Hampton, correct. The problem was bind_ip with both my mongodb and mysql. If you would like to answer this question, I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: dusan.bajic, yes VPC.

Answer (score 2):

Login with localhost first and execute the following and then try to login with -h10.0.0.23. Follow the steps below.

1. `mysql -u root -h localhost`
2. `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'10.0.0.23' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';`
3. `mysql -u root -psomepassword -h10.0.0.23`

Comment: This is a necessary step, however the problem was in bind_ip config option. Thanks for input though.